# Why does my resonant converter add more losses?

Tags: transistors, resonance, switching-losses, resonant-converter, zvs

I am currently designing a DC/DC converter transmitting energy from a solar panel to a load, using a transformer. The model of my circuit can be found on this figure:

[image]

To migitate the losses, I have added a capacitor C2 to form a resonant LLC tank and perform near-ZCS. The capacitance has been designed so that the switching frequency and the resonant frequency are the same. However, after analysing the P/V curves at the output of the circuit with and without this capacitor C2, one can clearly see that the circuit has more losses with the resonant tank than without, instead of the contrary.

[image]

After analysing the losses on various elements, I came to the conclusion that the elements creating more losses where the transistors and the input capacitance C3 on the primary side of the circuit. Their losses, again for a circuit with a resonant tank and for a circuit without one, can be seen on the following 2 figures:

[image]

[image]

However, when analysing the voltage and the current at the output of the bridge (V(out_bridge_+) and I(C2)), the circuit with a resonant converter seems to perform near-ZCS as seen on the following figure

[image]

My question is then why do the input capacitance, added so that we get the voltage characteristic of the solar panel, and the transistors produce more losses with a resonant tank, even though the circuit seems to be performing near-Zero Current Switching, which should reduce the losses ?

I can add graphs of the currents and voltages on the input capacitances and the transistors for both circuit if needed.

Comment: Does it improve if you lower the resonance frequency using a 10% bigger C2?

Comment: @Jens it does, but it now gives the same losses as without a capacitor, which makes the addition of the capacitor simply a waste of space and money. Is there no way to reduce the losses using a resonant converter ?

Comment: @andyaka I'm not sure I understand your comment. I agree that it seems that my circuit does not reduce the switching losses, so ZCS might not be implemented effectively. But why does adding a capacitor for resonance adds more conduction losses ?

Comment: @andyaka So as I said adding a capacitor for resonance is just a waste of space and money since it gives the same losses as not adding one, since the gain made on switching losses is lost on conduction losses ?

Comment: @andyaka upon closer inspection, it seems that the switching losses are caused in unwanted transistor current spikes at the time of switching, otherwise the current is indeed 0. Do you have any idea where these might be coming from and how to mitigate them?